# AWS API Gateway path params throws Null pointer exception in Java application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have an API gateway connected to a lambda function for a GET request by email using path params `/ticket-order/{email}`

[image: API Gateway path params]

I have also configured Integration Request where I'm setting a mapping template:

[image: Mapping Template]

In my Java application, I attempt to extract the params via the request like this:

```
    private APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent getTicketOrder(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent requestEvent, Context context) {
        var logger = context.getLogger();

        var pathParameters = requestEvent.getPathParameters();
        var email = pathParameters.get("email");
        // ...
    }
```

`pathParameters` seems to be null and throws a Null pointer.

In postman, I call the URI like this:

`http://my-api-gateway-uri/dev/ticket-order/jondoe@email.com`

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use the `Use Lambda Proxy integration` option, this will automatically map the parameters when the request is received.